# Looking to integrate open source sharepoint connector with SearchBlox

Tags: search, fast-search, search-results

Has anyone modified the open source google connector to work with [SearchBlox](http://www.searchblox.com/)? If not, how easy would it be to change the connector to index to the SearchBlox REST API. http://code.google.com/p/google-enterprise-connector-sharepoint/